# Is there a way to redirect a large file upload to cloud using pre-signed URLs?

Tags: amazon-s3, cloud, azure-blob-storage, backend, pre-signed-url

I am writing a public API service that allows users to upload very large video files for processing. I would like the upload process to not consume unnecessary bandwidth on my server by first receiving the file from the backend and then upload to a cloud storage provider.

My idea is to HTTP redirect the incoming PUT request to a pre-signed url and let client upload directly to cloud storage seamlessly.
Two options that I think could work so far are,

a. Make sure the client has formed the POST or PUT request properly, and just generate a presigned url and redirect to it.
b. Receive an improper POST or PUT request, change it to a proper format by adding the necessary parameters and then redirect.

I am not sure whether what I am describing is impossible or maybe I have just been using wrong keywords for search but I am stuck.

Comment: Yes, like this: [Uploading objects with presigned URLs - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html)

Comment: I ended up with a solution where the backend shares a resumable upload session retrieved from google storage and letting client upload directly using the session.

Comment: @mert can you please elaborate a bit more on the solution you came up with? Maybe as a proper answer, so that others could learn from what you did.

Comment: This sounds related: https://advancedweb.hu/how-to-solve-cors-problems-when-redirecting-to-s3-signed-urls/